# Wikipedia's Inverted Index for Python

Tags: python

I'm taking a look at Wikipedia's versions of Inverted Indexes, and I have a particular interest in the "Python" version. http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Inverted_index#Python
Essentially, the code's error is rather confusing for me.

Edit: The code is now fixed, thanks to the efforts of 2rs2ts.

```
from pprint import pprint as pp
from glob import glob
try: reduce
except: from functools import reduce
try:    raw_input
except: raw_input = input



def parsetexts(fileglob='*.txt'):
    texts, words = {}, set()
    for txtfile in glob(fileglob):
        with open(txtfile, 'r') as f:
            txt = f.read().split()
            words |= set(txt)
            texts[txtfile.split('\\')[-1]] = txt
    return texts, words

def termsearch(terms): # Searches simple inverted index
    return reduce(set.intersection,
                  (invindex[term] for term in terms),
                  set(texts.keys()))

texts, words = parsetexts()
print('\nTexts')
pp(texts)
print('\nWords')
pp(sorted(words))

invindex = {word:set(txt
                        for txt, wrds in texts.items() if word in wrds)
            for word in words}
print('\nInverted Index')
pp({k:sorted(v) for k,v in invindex.items()})

terms = ["what", "is", "it"]
print('\nTerm Search for: ' + repr(terms))
pp(sorted(termsearch(terms)))
```

Now, the error that occurs when I try to run a T1.txt file (as instructed) an error occurs (both in Python 2.7 and 3.3)

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/abcoleman/Documents/Intro2.py", line 38, in <module>
    pp(sorted(termsearch(terms)))
  File "/Users/abcoleman/Documents/Intro2.py", line 22, in termsearch
    set(texts.keys()))
  File "/Users/abcoleman/Documents/Intro2.py", line 21, in <genexpr>
    (invindex[term] for term in terms),
KeyError: 'what'
```

Is there some silly mistake that I am making? My instructor himself couldn't make sense of the error.

Comment: "what" isn't in `words` but it's in `terms`.

Comment: At least, that's what it's saying is happening. `words` is determined based on the content of the files in `fileglob`. What is the content of `T1.txt`? Have you tried printing `words` to see if it's as it should be?

Comment: The file consists of "what is it." And words doesn't even print. :\ Faulty Wiki code?

Comment: What do you mean, words doesn't even print?  Try inserting `print(words)` right before the last line, `pp(sorted(termsearch(terms))))`.

Comment: The same error occurs, but what was returned was `set()`

Comment: So it's like nothing is returning, to the Texts, Indexes, or anything at all..

Comment: This means that nothing was ever added to the set. Either when read, the file did not have any non-whitespace content (`f.read().split()` is supposed to read the contents of the file into a string and then separate substrings based on whitespace), or the `glob` did not return anything. It's more likely that the file did not return anything. Try `with open('InvertedIndex/T1.txt', 'r') as f: print(f.read().split())` (right under the other print I told you to add)

Comment: I found the error. `def parsetexts(fileglob='InvertedIndex/T*.txt'):` somehow couldn't read in `python Intro.py T1.txt`, which what I want to do, instead of hardcoding it… But if I hardcode it, it works, which is better than not.

Comment: I would look into [command line arguments](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_command_line_arguments.htm) in this case, then. The program couldn't find any files matching that glob pattern, but you weren't aware they just weren't there before glob will give you zip, nada, nothing instead of throwing an error when you try to explicitly `open` a non-existing file.

Comment: I will surely do that. Thank you very much, you've been a great help. Couldn't of found the issue without you.

Comment: Ok, I'm going to write up my answer and it'd be nice if you could accept it. It'll give me reputation, but also you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's walk through the program backwards in order to understand what went wrong. The exception you got means that the key `'what'` is not in `invindex`, but it is in `terms`. This make sense, since `terms = ["what", "is", "it"]`.

1. `'what'` not added to `invindex` caused the exception.

In turn, `invindex` is built using the list `words`, so that means `'what'` is not in `words`.

1. `'what'` was not added to `words`.
2. `invindex` was constructed from `words`, so `'what'` was not added to `invindex` as well. This caused the exception.

Since `words` is created with `texts, words = parsetexts()`, this means that `parsetexts()` is to blame.

1. <strike>`'what'` was not added to `words`.</strike>  `parsetexts()` did not put `'what'` in `words`.
2. `invindex` was constructed from `words`, so `'what'` was not added to `invindex` as well. This caused the exception.

`words` is a [`set`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html), and the line `words |= set(txt)` is a union operation, meaning that anything in `set(txt)` that is not already in `words` will be added. So that means `txt` does not contain `'what'` either. `txt` is created by reading files and separating each word (delimited by whitespace) and putting that into a list. So `'what'` was not in any of the files over which `parsetexts()` was iterating.

1. `'what'` was not found in any of the files over which `parsetexts()` was iterating.
2. <strike>`'what'` was not added to `words`.</strike>  `parsetexts()` did not put `'what'` in `words`.
3. `invindex` was constructed from `words`, so `'what'` was not added to `invindex` as well. This caused the exception.

You said you were using a file called `T1.txt`, and that ought to contain the word `'what'` in it, right? (I am assuming it does.) If the program had tried to open `T1.txt`, and it didn't exist or was unreadable, then you would have received an `IOError`, so that's not the problem either. And, if the only file you were using was `T1.txt` (again, I am assuming this is the issue), then it must be that the program *did not open `T1.txt`*.

The culprit is the [`glob`](http://docs.python.org/3.1/library/glob.html#glob.glob) performed. The documentation says thus:

> Return a possibly-empty list of path names that match pathname, which must be a string containing a path specification.

This means that the glob you specified does not include `T1.txt`. Since that was the only file you were using, chances are the glob didn't include anything. You can verify this by `print`ing `glob(fileglob)` or by just adding a `print` statement to the beginning of your `for` loop to see what you get - if no files were included in the glob, that latter approach will result in nothing being `print`ed.

1. `parsetexts()` did not iterate over any files because `glob(fileglob)` did not return anything. (or, it may have just not included `T1.txt`.)
2. `'what'` was not found in any of the files over which `parsetexts()` was iterating.
3. <strike>`'what'` was not added to `words`.</strike>  `parsetexts()` did not put `'what'` in `words`.
4. `invindex` was constructed from `words`, so `'what'` was not added to `invindex` as well. This caused the exception.

There you go! `print` is your friend :)